# Ajaxを使用してjsonデータを上手く取得できません

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

```js
< script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js" > < /script>

<script>
  
$(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
      $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url: "http:/ / localhost / cakephp - 2.6.3_smarty / sample1.json ",
        dataType:'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){

            $('p').html(data);

        }

      });
    });
});

</script>
```

```html
<p>変更前</p>
```

sample1.json

```
{"data1":,"data2":"}
```

上記のコードで実行していますが、出力結果が何も変わりません。
dataType:'json',をdataType:'html'にすると{"data1":,"data2":"}が出力されます。

どうしたら、jsonデータが取得できるでしょうか？
ご教授いただけると幸いです。

Comment: 送ったメッセージが本当に書かれたままならクオートが閉じていないように見えますが。fail()を追加すればエラーになったことがわかるのではないでしょうか。シリアライズはjsonSerialize()を使ってやることを強く推奨します。

Answer (score 1):

`{"data1":,"data2":"}`がJSONとして正しくないからでしょう。 sample1.jsonの内容を`{"data1":"","data2":""}`としたら動くと思います。